# Simulating fire with SPH particles

Tags: simulation, physics, modeling, particles, particle-system

I want to simulate fire using [SPH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics) particles. I understand the concept behind SPH but don't understand yet how to model the fire as a fluid.

- Do I have to add some temperature property to my particles from which I can derive there color?
- Do I have to take the surrounding air particles in account to create some buoyancy effect?
- Where do the particles get their heat from? Do I have to add a heat emitter over some space which creates warm particles so that the temperature then diffuses to the other particles over time?
- Are there some tutorials which describe my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, you'll have to have a temperature property. It really isn't fire if temperature isn't involved. And once you have temperature it's easy to get luminosity and color. (You probably don't have to worry about radiative heat transfer, at least not for a first effort.)

  If you handle pressure and gravity right, buoyancy will arise (ahem) naturally.

  You can start with a fixed heating element and an inert gas, then when you're ready you can introduce combustion as a differential equation: the rate of energy generation is a function of temperature, fuel pressure and oxygen pressure.

Comment: Do you have some sources which explain the relationship between temperature and luminosity/color?

Comment: @Etan: That depends. Do you want physically accurate radiation (a spectrum)? Or a range of colors that look good (RGB levels of a red-yellow-white range, adjusted by hand to the temperature ranges in you sim)?

Comment: I think that I'll use the fake approach here for a first effort. If it just depends on the temperature I think that linear interpolation between two rgb values would be sufficient - if that produces some nice images. Some question regarding the pressure thing: I have the fixed heating element and the inert gas now, but don't get where you'll have the oxygen pressure, or how exactly the differential equation looks like.

Comment: Additionaly, for the temperature changes: is it sufficient to just set the initial values and afterwards use SPH to get the new values after each time step? What about constants that I could use? Or is it just trial and error?